# Set STATIC_URL on Heroku but getting ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/login/

Tags: python, django, heroku

Getting:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/login/ You're using the staticfiles app
>   without having set the required STATIC_URL setting.

after I deployed the Django app to Heroku:

https://rtd2015.herokuapp.com/admin/

I'm also getting a 404 on the root URL: rtd2015.herokuapp.com.

Thanks

## base.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
from os import environ
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates/'),
)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com', '.researchthroughdesign.org',]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'gunicorn',
    'markdown_deux',
    'storages',
    'site_2015',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MARKDOWN_DEUX_STYLES = {
    "STYLE": {
        "extras": {
            "code-friendly": None,
        },
        "safe_mode": False,
    },
}

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)
```

## production.py

```
from base import *

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'rtd2015'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'app.settings.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.settings.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../srv/assets'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = 'http://rtd2015.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://rtd2015.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'http://rtd2015.s3.amazonaws.com/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://rtd2015.s3.amazonaws.com/media/'
```

Comment: I don't think you are using production.py as django's settings module. Check your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment var.